# Equivalent of DataTemplateSelector in .NET Portable Subset

Tags: c#, wpf, portable-class-library

I am running into this issue. 
With normal WPF application DataTemplateSelector class gets resolved when I include

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

However this time I am using ".NET Portable Subset" targeting .NET for Windows Store apps and .NET Framework 4.5.

And I get "Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference" error for DataTemplateSelector.

Is there any new method out there for .NET Portable Subset to do the same?
Or am I actually missing out on some Assemblies?

Comment: WPF specific types such as `DataTemplateSelector` are not available in any portable subset; UI components are left out of PCL. Separate your code into portable and WPF specific, and place the WPF specific code in a separate .NET only assembly.

Answer (score 3):

DataTemplateSelector is something you implement specifically for WPF. You want that in a library that is only intended for use with WPF, not a portable class library (PCL).

The aim of the PCL is to share code between platforms, taken to the extreme, you wouldn't want the selector in an Android or iOS Xamarin solution.

I typically structure my solutions as:

- App (WPF Application)
- Common UI (Class library containing convertors, templateselectors, generic controls)
- ViewModels (Portable Class Library)

Beyond that, if my view models require target specific implementations - such as file access, I create interfaces in ViewModels and add a target specific solution for implementations.

Note these names are implied meanings, I don't intend to start a debate :)

Hope that helps